# how to hide other application from my application from list of apps android

Tags: android

Could anybody please help me find a way to hide other application from my application. I'm retrieving a list of apps installed with check boxes and when I check some apps, those should be hidden from the application list in emulator. I've searched in google but I couldn't find it. I am waiting for help....
Thanks,

Comment: I think, the simple answer is "you cannot do this".  The list of application is installed internally by Android.  If you're writing a custom launcher, then you can filter that list down using whatever criteria you like.  However you can't simply hide it in default launcher or in the list of the installed applications in device settings.  You may be able to remove the application's apk and hide it that way though, but you may need some special permissions for that.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  If you are presenting a list of apps (in your own application) retrieving them from the PackageManager or something.  You could easily just create an exclusion list of your own (or based on the checkboxes a user selects) and remove them from the List you send to the adapter to setup your list manually.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But i m not want to hide from listview items, I m trying to hide from applications list which are viewing in emulator applist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom launcher, in which you control which apps are shown (within your own launcher) by creating a list of apps within your own launcher.

You will not be able to hide apps from the general system.  Android uses the Role\Group security model from Linux, and you (an app running within the Android OS) wouldn't have the security permissions to hide apps from the user on a system level - to have that access right, you would need to be root.

Bottom line, you cannot create an app to hide other apps from the Android System (or the user).  This is due to security restrictions (which make sense - malicious apps would be able to hide themselves from the user, which would be a bad thing).

If you wanted to do this in the emulator - you could actually make the changes in the source code of Android (which you can download and modify to your pleasure).  This would work within an emulator only (you wouldn't be able to install that on a real phone without hacking, or rooting).

Comment: sounds reasonable. BUT, how does "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkyeah.apphider" and "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinkyeah.smartlockfree" work?

Comment: The Play App does NOT hide system apps.  In order to do this yourself, you will need to create an app that is a system launcher (with higher level of access).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do that without hacking platform (or rooting it).

Comment: I didn't find this answer constructive, but accidentally down-voted it (which seems to be permanent, if I click up, it marks it as plus 1).  Sorry for the down-vote - but maybe you can explain more "why" you can't do it, to make the answer more helpful.  (I hate one line: "you can't do that" answers.

Comment: Sorry if my question is wrong. But my requirement is to do a simple app like app hider for keeping some apps in hide from other users

Comment: @Booger - you can revoke your downvote by clicking arrow-down again now (it required answer being edited, which is done nowI). As for the answer itself - for me OP asked about how to make his app to be able to hide **other** apps that way, it could be hidden from PackageManager (something like [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ramdroid.appquarantinepro)). And this cannot be done w/o rooting.

Comment: Hi actually I don't know about rooting concept could you provide any link regarding that..