# How to disable other apps android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write a study helper app that disables other apps (which the user chooses as distracting) for a certain period of time. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Why dont you show us what you have tried first, and then we can help you from there.

Comment: Start by reading Android source code? (I am almost not kidding)

Comment: I guess I'm kind of new and don't know where to start. Unfortunately google searching for 45 minutes hasn't helped me at all..

Comment: I'm also looking for this, I'm a developer for XYZ company and I want to know how to disable my competitors' app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible without a few workarounds, because you can't control, what the default launcher is showing. You could create a custom launcher which only shows the apps you want.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178910/how-to-hide-other-application-from-my-application-from-list-of-apps-android) explains, why modifying the default launcher doesn't work.

Another way would be to modify the AndroidManifest.xml of an installed app. Some time ago there was a permissions manager which unpacked an apk, modified the manifest, repacked it and reinstalled the app. Maybe something similar could solve your problem. Unfortunately I can't find that app at the moment.

However this method has two disadvantages:

- every time an app gets enabled or disabled the user must click to reinstall that app
- this may violate googles guidelines, so your app could get banned from play store

Answer (score 1):

To freeze apps you'll need to have the package manager disable them. You can do this by either [setApplicationEnabledSetting](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setApplicationEnabledSetting%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29), or through a shell with `pm disable com.example.app`. You used to be able to do this without root, but it's possible they have added restrictions to it in newer versions.

Keep in mind that this will completely disable the application, not just hide it. So you'll definitely want to make sure to re-enable it again or you're likely to get some complaints.